# Salesforce CPQ (SteelBrick) API

Tags: rest-api, steelbrick

I want to use the Steelbrick features (Quote Editor, Reconfigure Line etc) without using CPQ Quote Editor form Salesforce instead I want to leverage REST API so that I can get the same access from another web layer. Is anyone worked on this kind of requirement?

Thanks.